# Symfony2 and Doctrine Mysql Test Database Persist

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a basic OneToMany relationship between an `Administrator`and `Role`.

The owning side is Administrator:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\PublicBundle\Entity\Role", mappedBy="administrator", cascade="persist")
 **/
private $roles;

public function __construct() {
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The inverse side is Role.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\PublicBundle\Entity\Administrator", inversedBy="roles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="admin_id", referencedColumnName="admin_id")
 **/
private $administrator;
```

The `Administrator` can have many `Roles` like `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_USER`.

The code to save them atomically is...

```
    $administrator = new Administrator();
    $administrator->setName('Mario');
    $administrator->setLastname('Superman');
    $administrator->setUsername('mario@gmail.com');
    $administrator->setPassword('password');

    $role_admin = new Role();
    $role_admin->setRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    $role_admin->setAdministrator($administrator);

    $role_user = new Role();
    $role_user->setRole('ROLE_USER');
    $role_user->setAdministrator($administrator);

    $administrator->setRoles($role_admin);
    $administrator->setRoles($role_user);

    $em->persist($administrator);
    $em->persist($role_user);
    $em->persist($role_admin);
    $em->flush();
```

Basic stuff. This code is inside a Symfony2 controller that is called via Ajax. It throws an `Integrity constraint violation` where he says that he cannot put null in `admin_id` column beacuse it is null. It also emmits two notices that say `undefined index role_id`.

The strange stuff is that the rows are not saved but the `admin_id` on the `administrators` table gets incremented.

The even stranger stuff is that I have a UnitTest that does the same thing (literally the same thing with the same code) and persists the entities.

So how code test code work but the same code in the live controller doesn't?

EDIT: I call the controller via Ajax and it doesn't get persisted but if I go straight to the url that make a request with ajax, it gets persisted two times. Ones for the ajax post request and the second when i go straight to link on the browser. Am I missing something basic here beacuse I have a feeling that I am.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that my database was named as `test_suite` what mysql regarded as a test database. I don't know the details but it seems that every database that has `test_` like names is regared by mysql in special rules. As I said, i don't know the details but I couldn't make a transactional insert statement in that kind of database.

When I created a new database called `suit`, everything worked.

[This blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/the_test_database)
doesn't say that transactional insert statements are prohibited in test databases, but it seems that it is a bad idea to name your database `test_` like. I didn't know that and had to learn it the hard way